# Overlap of .bin links on npm

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am requiring 2 packages that will make the same link on the `.bin` ([osprey](https://github.com/mulesoft/osprey) and [osprey-cli](https://github.com/mulesoft/osprey-cli))

Having both on the *package.json* and since both use the name `osprey` for the cli, will make the latter to override the first one.

So my question is, is it possible to override the output link to `.bin` ?